Unity x Visual Studio Community 2022
I'm using Unity version 2022.3.23f1
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.1
The issue is, when I have VStudio open and I create a new script in the Unity Editor and open the new script. When I go to type something like Start or Update, normally it will auto complete it for me.
Some extra context is that I know why it's not auto-completing, because for some reason when I open a new script while VStudio is open it doesn't take the using statements i.e using UnityEngine etc. All of sudden it's not doing that anymore. I'm not sure why this happens other than it started the other day after I updated to the previous version of VStudio Community (17.11.0 I think). Only when I completely close VStudio and reopen it does it recognize the using statements and then everything works fine. Another small problem is that I don't know if this is a Unity issue or a VS issue, hints why I came here in the hope that someone that uses both could help.
VStudio Extensions: HLSL Tools For Visual Studio

is it working for other scenarios?

If you mean if it's working in other Unity projects. No, it's not.
To be honest I'm not really all that worried about it, it's just a minor annoyance.
Things I've tried

Restarting computer
Updating VStudio to the latest version (17.11.1 Time of Post)
Repairing VStudio installation.

Short Clip of the problem
*Small edit, I realized why it wasn't working when I was typing MonoBehaviour, I forgot I had changed it to an interface class. Other than that it does display the issue I'm talking about.

Are you working within a .csproj Project - or in "Miscellaneous files"-mode without a .csproj?
